# ARITHMETIC OPERATIONS in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

FIRST THREE ARITHMETIC FUNCTION WORKING

```
select CreditLimit,'sum'=CreditLimit+Zip from Customers

select CreditLimit,'sub'=CreditLimit-Zip from Customers

select CreditLimit,'div'=CreditLimit/Zip from Customers
```

LAST TWO ARTHMETIC FUNCTION OR NOT WORKING SHOW ERROE

```
select CreditLimit,'mod'=CreditLimit%Zip from Customers

ERROR DISPALY: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smallmoney.

select CreditLimit,'mul'=CreditLimit*Zip from Customers

ERROR DISPALY:The data types smallmoney and nchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.
```

Advance Thanks friends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the column `ZIP` is an `nchar` data type .You need to convert it into `smallmoney` before performing the arithmetic operation

```
select CreditLimit,'mod'=CreditLimit%convert(smallmoney,Zip) from Customers
```